# Implement a dictionary application for a regional language

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, desktop-application

I need to implement a dictionary application like "Word Web" for a regional language. I am having some basic question like

1. How to store the content?I mean in which type of file?
2. How to search for a specific word from the file?

As language is not English it is becoming more challenging for me. Please suggest how to proceed with this? (I am a .Net C# programmer.)

Comment: Are you asking how to store data in some representation you can use? This question is basically unanswerable, because we dont know the requirements. We could suggest things, but you haven't indicated what you have tried so far.

Comment: [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) maybe.

Comment: @Tejs my requirement is to implement an application. Which can be installed and it will have an interface where user can search for any word's meaning and it will display the result accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries for most languages only consist of a couple hundred thousand words. You can perfectly store every word in a dictionary on a table in a database and this way, take advantage of the Database engine to perform searches efficiently, even implement sorting, etc., etc.

You can download [SQL SERVER EXPRESS EDITION](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) which is completely free. You can find dictionaries for most languages in text format from Mozilla Firefox dictionaries add-ins. You can potentially load these text files into a table in your database and use that for your app.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But I was trying to have something which user can download and install it and it will work like a desktop application. As you suggested user have to install SQL Server and all those which user might not like. So I was trying have something installable package kind of solution.

Comment: Sql Server Express Edition was just a suggestion. If you want a self-contained DB you can use SQL Lite: http://www.sqlite.org/ The point I am trying to make is that you do not need to reinvent the wheel to perform searches efficiently. A database will do a better job and it will offer many more benefits.